# Django - Write a test function that runs once before all test cases

Tags: python, django

I have this code here that creates entries in the table because they're required in order to create a new post. You need a user and a goal and goal category. I heard setUp() runs before every test so that's an issue as it could try to great instances that already exists. I'd like to run setUp() once before all the tests are run. How do I do this?

```
class PostTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        GoalCategory.objects.create(category='other', emoji_url='url')
        self.user = UserFactory()
        self.goal = GoalFactory()

    def test_create_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post'),
                                    data=json.dumps({'creator_id': str(self.user.uuid),
                                                     'goal_id': str(self.goal.uuid),
                                                     'body': 'Some text #Test'}),
                                    content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def test_no_goal_create_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post'),
                                    data=json.dumps({'creator_id': str(self.user.uuid),
                                                     'goal_id': 'some messed up UUID',
                                                     'body': 'Some text #Test'}),
                                    content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def test_no_user_create_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post'),
                                    data=json.dumps({'creator_id': 'messed up user',
                                                     'goal_id': str(self.goal.uuid),
                                                     'body': 'Some text #Test'}),
                                    content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Here's a link to [setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData).

Comment: I'm getting this error 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "cheers_goal" violates foreign key constraint "cheers_goal_creator_id_id_b40361df_fk_cheers_user_uuid"
DETAIL:  Key (creator_id_id)=(ff45ab97-53e7-40ce-9310-9ea93c024378) is not present in table "cheers_user".' This tells me that something weird is going on with the data. When I run all tests alone without the rest it runs fine.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I'm running this on PostGres says it runs before every test on DBs without transaction support. Dunno if PostGres is included in that set.

Comment: Each test is enclosed in a transaction and gets rolled back after execution, so you shouldn't get the `already exists` problems

Comment: @user8714896 pgsql supports transactions, and based on the error you presented, it doesn't seem like an duplication error.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr no doesn't seem like it. I don't know what it is cause I'm not trying to do a user look at up in any of the calls so it's weird.

Comment: @user8714896 are you certain this error is occurring during the tests? Do you mind also sharing your `cheers_user` and `cheers_goal` models, and the serializer/view associated with your `post` path?

Answer (score 4):

Actually for creating Django models the right answer is [`setupTestData()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData). That method runs in database transaction which rolls back before the tests ends. Therefore all testing data are cleaned once the tests are done.
The code is:

```py
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        GoalCategory.objects.create(category='other', emoji_url='url')
        cls.user = UserFactory()
        cls.goal = GoalFactory()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use setUpClass (classmethod) and override it in you TestCase class
"Hook method for setting up class fixture before running tests in the class."

```
class PostTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        GoalCategory.objects.create(category='other', emoji_url='url')
        cls.user = UserFactory()
        cls.goal = GoalFactory()
```